# Saving best model in keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I use the following code when training a model in keras

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(Dense(1))

model_2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(X, y, epochs=15, validation_split=0.4, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor], verbose=False)

model.predict(X_test)
```

but recently I wanted to get the best trained model saved as the data I am training on gives a lot of peaks in "high val_loss vs epochs" graph and I want to use the best one possible yet from the model.

Is there any method or function to help with that?

Answer (score 95):

[EarlyStopping](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) and [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) is what you need from Keras documentation.

You should set `save_best_only=True` in ModelCheckpoint. If any other adjustments needed, are trivial.

Just to help you more you can see a usage [here on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/cbryant/keras-cnn-with-pseudolabeling-0-1514-lb/).

---

Adding the code here in case the above Kaggle example link is not available:

```
model = getModel()
model.summary()

batch_size = 32

earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=0, mode='min')
mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint('.mdl_wts.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
reduce_lr_loss = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=7, verbose=1, epsilon=1e-4, mode='min')

model.fit(Xtr_more, Ytr_more, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=50, verbose=0, callbacks=[earlyStopping, mcp_save, reduce_lr_loss], validation_split=0.25)
```

Comment: Could you please attach the example here? If the link brokes, the answer will become useles

Comment: I am getting a `Keyerror: 'lr' ` because of ReduceLROnPlateau . Why ??

Comment: @NeerajKumar: Please read https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/ and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau. If reading these docs didn't help you, then please post a separate question along with the part of the code that is causing an error.

Comment: I am working with tf.keras (tf v'2.10.0') and had to pass the filepath as directory and not .hdf5 file.
`ModelCheckpoint('saved_models/', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')`

Answer (score 47):

[`EarlyStopping`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping)'s `restore_best_weights` argument will do the trick:

> **restore_best_weights:** whether to restore model weights from the epoch with the best value of the monitored quantity. If False, the model weights obtained at the last step of training are used.

So not sure how your `early_stopping_monitor` is defined, but going with all the default settings and seeing you already imported `EarlyStopping` you could do this:

```py
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    min_delta=0,
    patience=0,
    verbose=0,
    mode='auto',
    baseline=None,
    restore_best_weights=True
)
```

And then just call `model.fit()` with `callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor]` like you already do.

Comment: This is the right answer. The reason why other answers have more votes is probably due to the fact that `restore_best_weights` has been introduced in [Keras 2.2.3](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.2.3), which has been released on October 2018, i.e. after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48286003/738017).

Comment: Man... Keras is just *too* easy!

Comment: will it still restore the best weights when it didn't manage to earlystop but finish all epochs

Comment: please note currently, `restore_best_weights=False` by default!

Answer (score 15):

I guess `model_2.compile` was a typo.
This should help if you want to save the best model w.r.t to the val_losses -

```py
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model-{epoch:03d}-{acc:03f}-{val_acc:03f}.h5', 
    verbose=1, 
    monitor='val_loss',
    save_best_only=True, 
    mode='auto'
)  

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=15, validation_split=0.4, callbacks=[checkpoint], verbose=False)
```