# Do predictions with .hdf5 weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Using the Keras API and Tensorflow, I am training a neural network. During the epochs, I have saved the weights of the hidden layers (as .hdf5 files).

After all the epochs, I want to make predictions based on the 'best epoch'. However, I have no clue how to load these weights into `model.predict()` properly. Who can tell me how to do this?

Comment: Just to better understand your goal, do you want to persist your model so that you can retrieve it at a later point in time to score your data? If so, you don't need to save the individual weights of the layers into separate hdf5 files. You can just save the entire NN itself and it'll retain the architecture as well as the weights of the layers. Here's the [info](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) in the docs for doing that.

Comment: Thats indeed why I want to save these particular weights. If I save my entire model, won't that just save the weights of the last epoch, rather than those of the 'best' epoch?

Comment: Ah gotcha. Yes, it would save the from the last epoch. In this case, you would have to load your model architecture (or redefine the architecture), and then call `model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')`. So 1) save your model architecture, 2) save the best model weights, then 3) load the model and load the weights. The docs has an example on saving the architecture.

Comment: The last epoch may not be the best model, you can use checkpoints to make sure you save the best model. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285129/saving-best-model-in-keras